# Why I do not see all of the folders in Eclipse package Explorer that I see in File Explorer

Tags: java, maven, meta-inf, serviceloader, package-explorer

I created a Maven modul in Eclipse, and there I have a folder called 'target'. That on I see in package explorer in Eclipse. If I open it there are several folder. If I open it in File Explorer on Windows I see even more folder, e.g. one of them called classes/META-INF/services/* which I created using annotations before some classes in the modul. Why I only see those in the Windows File Explorer and not in the Eclipse Package Explorer and how to change that?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are looking in the "Project Explorer", which understands a project layout, and knows the difference between source files, generated files, project files, resource directories and so on. It doesn't necessarily present you the files in the same tree structure as the they appear in the filesystem.

If you want to see the the actual file layout, you need the "File explorer". Other views can be opened in the "Window -> Show View -> " menu.

Comment: thank you for your answer @slim. In this situtation should ServicerLoader work right? I am getting Nullpointerexception in the line: 
  JmjrstPlugin plugin = ld.iterator().next();

Comment: If you're not developing a plugin, you shouldn't see NPEs from plugins. But you might have found a bug.